# Convert escpaed JSON array in a string to an actual array with DataWeave

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mule4

How to remove an escaped JSON array contained in an string (need to remove \ sign and convert to array) to a JSON array using DataWeave transformation.

Input data:

```
{
     "values": [
       {
       "start": "{\"value\":[{\"classifier\":\"data1\",\"params\":\"1234\",\"year\":\"1930\",\"month\":null,\"day\":null,\"source\":null}],\"primary\":true,\"param4\":\"1930\"}"
       },
       {
       "end": "{\"value\":[{\"classifier\":\"data1\",\"params\":\"1234\",\"year\":\"2014\",\"month\":null,\"day\":null,\"source\":null}],\"primary\":true,\"param4\":\"2014\"}"
       }
     ]
}
```

Comment: The input strings are not malformed. They have an escaped array, otherwise putting a JSON array into a string would really be a malformed JSON.

Answer (score 2):

What you have got is a string representation of a JSON that is inside another JSON, and you are trying to get the JSON back from String. The `\` signs are there for escaping the double quotes inside the values of JSON payload, it is not malformed. You just need to [`read`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-read) the string back to JSON.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
    values: payload.values 
              map ((value) -> value mapObject ($$): read($, "application/json"))
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly not working here: https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/ Got an error of "You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("values")
  2: Name ("values")

But it expects one of these combinations:"

Comment: You need to wrap your payload that you have shared in question with `{}` as the one that you shared is not a valid json. Only after that it is processable.

Comment: `{"values": [.....]}` like this

Comment: In real environment (since this is only part of all Json data) I got this error:  "Exception while reading 'begin' as 'application/json' cause by:
Unexpected character 'b' at root@[1:1] (line:column), expected false or true or null or {...} or [...] or number but was , while reading `root` as Json.

Comment: that last error looks like it was an incorrect payload

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
 values:payload.values map {
     ($ mapObject ((value, key, index) ->  (key):read(value,"application/json") ))
 }
```

Output:

```
    {
  "values": [
    {
      "start": {
        "value": [
          {
            "classifier": "data1",
            "params": "1234",
            "year": "1930",
            "month": null,
            "day": null,
            "source": null
          }
        ],
        "primary": true,
        "param4": "1930"
      }
    },
    {
      "end": {
        "value": [
          {
            "classifier": "data1",
            "params": "1234",
            "year": "2014",
            "month": null,
            "day": null,
            "source": null
          }
        ],
        "primary": true,
        "param4": "2014"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```